# Universally catenary and all its formal fibers over minimal members are Cohen-Macaulay but it has a nonCohen-Macaulay formal fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Please help me to find a Noetherian local ring $R$ such that: $R$ is universally catenary and all its formal fibers over minimal members of $Spec(R)$ are Cohen-Macaulay but $R$ has a nonCohen-Macaulay formal fiber. I want to check Cohen-Macaulay property of all formal fibers over minimal member of the domain constructed by M. Brodmann and C. Rotthaus (http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2043342?uid=3739320&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103058198853). The construction of that ring is very complicated so I can not check up to now.
Thank you very much !

Comment: You give a link in restricted access, but for AMS journals there are free access links as well; for your article: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1983-087-04/S0002-9939-1983-0687624-1/S0002-9939-1983-0687624-1.pdf